# What causes GitHub Push to hang while writing objects

Tags: github, netbeans

I have a rather large (1300 files, 1.6GB) Netbeans Java project that I've been trying to set up on GitHub using the inbuilt GitHub facilities of Netbeans. After Commit I attempt to do a Push. It quickly gets to 22% and just hangs there saying it's writing objects. What are the possible causes of this?

Also, is the writing it's referring to on the GitHub server or my machine?

Obviously, am a GitHub newbie.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the Repository and started over and it worked.

Full disclosure: On my first attempt I had included several  (unnecessary) files over 100MB each and the Push failed with an appropriate message. So, I "deleted" them my unselecting the check boxes in the NB dialog and did a Commit, then attempted a Push. Apparently, this created an *unreported* error that caused the hang.